# Mongoose sometimes inserts after promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

I've been struggling with these for weeks, I'm using a NPM called "Binance" that connects with a the Binance API, its creator gives us this code to work with:

```
binanceRest.newOrder({
    timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
    symbol: stack_item.bns_market,
    side: stack_item.bns_side,
    timeInForce: stack_item.bns_timeinforce,
    quantity: stack_item.bns_quantity, //min 0.05
    price: stack_item.bns_price,
    type: stack_item.bns_type
}).then((data) => {

}).catch((err) => {

});
```

This **does** **create an order consistently**, however when I get to the promise I want to  insert a document with the data it returns, like this:

```
binanceRest.newOrder({
    timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
    symbol: stack_item.bns_market,
    side: stack_item.bns_side,
    timeInForce: stack_item.bns_timeinforce,
    quantity: stack_item.bns_quantity, //min 0.05
    price: stack_item.bns_price,
    type: stack_item.bns_type
}).then((data) => {
    var data_insert = {
        orl_user: stack_item.bns_user,
        orl_exchange: 'Binance',
        orl_market: stack_item.bns_market,
        orl_id: data.orderId,
        orl_data: data,
        createdAt: new Date()
    }

    order_list_model.create(data_insert, function(err){
        if(err){ console.log(err) }else{
            console.log('insert_order_list');
        }
    });
}).catch((err) => {

});
```

The program **always** displays the console message "insert_order_list", but **it doesn't always insert** anything, it seems to insert randomly, sometimes it does sometimes it doesn't.

I tried testing inserting 3 times to see what happened, it seems to insert only twice.

I've never seen this behavior before, how can this be so random??

The model I'm inserting to has no restrictions like unique or required. And it has never inserted data with missing fields either.

Comment: This code exists within a function and that function is called from some other function presumably. You really need to expose those wider aspects in order to get a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your `then` function is just going off into nowhere. Sometimes it'll resolve before you check to see if it inserted anything, sometimes it won't. It'll always resolve *eventually* (which is why you're always seeing the log), but you need to manage your promises more carefully to ensure that things happen in the order you expect.

To fix the issue, have your `then` function return a new promise which resolves in the `order_list_model.create` callback.

Comment: Provide example please